# Cloning a disk twice results in binary differences

Tags: hard-drive, clone

I'm using HDD RawCopy to clone a disk to a file twice (different files). The disk in question is a  SATADOM connected to my computer using a SATA to USB cable.

Somehow, when I make the clone twice in a row I get two different binary content. Not all of it but some addresses here and there are different. Some sections are very different, most are the same.

I thought it might have been the OS messing around so I booted in "Mini XP" from Hiren's Boot CD and made the copy from there.

I would expect the exact same content however many times I make the copy since it is a byte-per-byte copy.

Can anyone tell me why that is ?

Comment: Have you tried formatting the SATA to the file system type of the source disk you're cloning it from to see if it's still an issue if you do that first? Just a quick thought but it's been a while since I've cloned disk but I recall a similar problem with NTFS partition images pushes at least... perhaps it may be related so this is just a quick thought or suggestion only if it's simple enough for you to test in your setup.

Comment: Oh no I'm sorry, I made a mistake in the explanation of the scenario. I'm cloning the SATADOM twice to two files and then comparing those two files together. Then I get binary differences.